# React pass component as react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am wanting to pass a component to another component as prop, the component needs to change based on whether or not the user is authenticated, in the example below my  component is rendering, but the component passed via the navigation prop is not,

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import Layout from './core/Layout';

import LoggedInHeader from './core/LoggedInHeader';
import LoggedOutHeader from './core/LoggedOutHeader';

const authenticated = false;

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Layout navigation={() => authenticated ? <LoggedInHeader /> : <LoggedOutHeader /> } />
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

If I do,

```
<Layout navigation={<LoggedInHeader />} />
```

It works fine, but I need to show a logged out user a different navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need the action binding `()=>{}`

Just do it like this

```
 <Layout navigation={ authenticated ? <LoggedInHeader /> : <LoggedOutHeader /> } />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this

```
<Layout navigation={authenticated ? <LoggedInHeader /> : <LoggedOutHeader /> } />
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the 'cleaner' approach will be to pass boolean as prop to the `Layout` component (e.g. `<Layout authenticated={authenticated}`).

Then in the `Layout` component you return (or render):

```
<div>
  {this.props.authenticated ? (
    <LoggedInHeader />
  ) : (
    <LoggedOutHeader />
  )}
</div>
```

I assume your layout component is more complicated (it's a container), so it's better to let it decide what should be rendered.